# Split dataset into clusters and save each cluster on a separate pdf document in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

Using the 'mtcars' dataset, how can one split the dataset into clusters using the 'Carb' field and output each grid on a separate pdf document with the Carb value being the name of the pdf document. I am new in R and the solutions I have found enable one to save each cluster on a different page of a pdf document. Have not found one where its possible to save each cluster as a separate document.

Comment: `mtcars` is a built-in data set, you don't have to post it, it's enough to refer to it. Post the code you've tried instead. And "clusters" is a broad theme, can you explain better what you want?

Comment: Here is the code. By cluster, i mean that all cars with the same 'Carb' value (eg 1) to be in one pdf document,  cars with a different carb value (e.g 2) to be in a different pdf page.     df <- mtcars



pdf("multipage.pdf")
lapply(split(df, df$carb), function(d) {
  grid::grid.newpage()
  gridExtra::grid.table(d)
}
)
dev.off()

Answer (score 1):

You can create pdfs for each part of dataset using approach of parameterized reports in Rmarkdown and not just creating tables, you can create a whole report for each clusters of the dataset.

So to do that, we need to first create a template rmarkdown file containing code for printing data as table where we also need to specify `params` in yaml of the file.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "None"
date: '2022-07-26'
output: pdf_document
params:
  carb: 1
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown table

```{r, echo=FALSE}
data(mtcars)

df <- mtcars[mtcars$carb %in% params$carb,]

knitr::kable(df, caption = paste("mtcars table for carb", params$carb))
```
````

Then from a separate R file (r script) or from console run this code which will create six pdfs for each value of carb

```
lapply(unique(mtcars$carb), function(carb_i) {
  rmarkdown::render("tables.Rmd",
                    params = list(carb = carb_i),
                    output_file = paste0("table_for_carb",carb_i, ".pdf"))
})
```

So, for example, `table_for_carb1.pdf` looks like this

[image: table for carb 1]

To know more how to create parameterized report with rmarkdown, [see here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with package `gridExtra`.

```
library(gridExtra)

sp <- split(mtcars, mtcars$carb)

lapply(seq_along(sp), \(i) {
  carb <- names(sp)[i]
  filename <- sprintf("carb%s.pdf", carb)
  pdf(filename)
  grid.table(sp[[i]])
  dev.off()
})
```

---

To write the clusters to the same PDF file, one table per page, start by exporting the first table, then, in the `lapply` loop go to next page and export the next table. The new pages must be between the tables and there must already exist a page (the 1st) before starting a new one for the next table.

And since the filename doesn't depend on the number of carburetors, the code can be simplified and rewritten without the need for `seq_along`.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

sp <- split(mtcars, mtcars$carb)

pdf("carb.pdf")
grid.table(sp[[1]])
lapply(sp[-1], \(x) {
  grid.newpage()
  grid.table(x)
})
dev.off()
```